# I am trying to learn triggers on my sql and getting the following errors

Tags: mysql, triggers

This is the code I am executing

```
create trigger salarydifff  
after update on office  
for each row  
declare sal_diff number  
begin  
sal_diff := :new.salary- :old.salary  
end
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare sal_diff number begin sal_diff := :new.salary- :old.salary end' at line 4
```

Comment: @juergend Didn't get your comment. Can you please elaborate

Comment: You should get a DB tool like MySQL Workbench and then go through the errors step by step. Look up how to declare a variable. The error shows the exact position of the problem -> declare. There is no `number` data type without a precision.

Comment: I tried and changed it to INTEGER as well but it didn't make much difference @juergend Can you help me with the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like Oracle not mysql
Mysql would look like this

```
drop trigger if exists salarydiff;
delimiter //

create trigger salarydifff  
after update on office 
for each row  
begin
declare sal_diff integer ; 

set sal_diff = new.amt - old.amt ; 
end //

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks a lot @P.Salmon

Comment: Also i have one more doubt. I want to display the value of the variable sal_diff but as a trigger cannot return a value, i am unable to display the value. Which is the other method to meet the required standard. @P.Salmon

Comment: If you want to log changes then you could create a log file and insert to it from the trigger - and then select from that at a time convenient to you.

Comment: can you please elaborate? @P.Salmon